# ORDER BY in DB2 SQL Query to match sort in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, sorting, db2, sql-order-by

I have a DB2 SQL query pulling an ID field (let's call it [ID]) that needs to be sorted in the way excel sorts ascending, for the purpose of speeding up lookup formulas that happen later in the process of my workflow.

```
SELECT [ID] FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY [ID]
```

My issue is that the DB2 code is sorting the data with the '01~010000~AAAAAB...', '01~010000~AAAAAC...', etc. rows to the top, and excel is sorting them to the bottom, below the '01~010000~000001...' rows, which is what I need for my lookup formulas to operate correctly.

So DB2 is sorting like this -

```
01~010000~AAAAAB~100000000000~01~01  
01~010000~AAAAAC~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~ZAAAAA~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~000001~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~000001~000000000001~01~01
```

And Excel is sorting like this -

```
01~010000~000001~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~000001~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~AAAAAB~100000000000~01~01  
01~010000~AAAAAC~000000000001~01~01  
01~010000~ZAAAAA~000000000001~01~01
```

Is there something I can do with my DB2 SQL in the ORDER BY to match how Excel sorts the data?

EDIT: To answer the question below, I'm afraid I don't have all of that technical information.  I *think* it's z/os, but I don't know the answer to any of that other stuff.  Any time I have had to google for answers about DB2 SQL, the examples work, so I guess whatever the rest of the world is using is what I have?

Comment: What is the Db2-server platform (z/os , i-series, linux/unix/windows)?  What is the collating sequence defined for that database?  Please EDIT your question to add new fact s(don't use comments)

Comment: The collating-sequence and encoding determine the order. You *have to know* these things when programming. Talk with your DBA or database support people on-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the EBCDIC collation sequence sort order is used.
Try to sort by the [COLLATION_KEY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_collationkey.html) function with some appropriate collation-name constant as 2-nd argument.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark!  that is exactly what I needed.  I ended up using -   ORDER BY COLLATION_KEY(RTRIM([ID]), 'UCA400R1_AS_S2')